# Head on collision of two black holes

Tags: black-holes, large-hadron-collider

LHC was built to collide two atomic particles to study contents within them. There are millions and billions of black holes present throughout galaxies. As collision between the galaxies is common in the universe. What is the possibiloty of us to witness head on collision of two black holes (near speed of light) which would scatter their internal material, so that we can get more insight into the black hole?

Comment: Colliding black holes is what LIGO was expected to detect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO

Comment: I'm not sure how close to the speed of light two black holes attracted by gravity would colide with each other, it might be close to the speed of light, but such a collision wouldn't, at least not directly "scatter" internal material.  It might scatter energy in the form of gravitational waves, but I gather that's still up for debate.   Somebody smarter than me should probably answer this in more detail.

Comment: It's worth noting that a direct collision in space is rare.   Much more common is a miss, followed by an orbital dance and spiral in towards each other.   As black holes get close enough to each other, they would spiral into each other quite quickly.

Comment: The mention of LHC seems to be a *non sequitur* here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Space is big. Really big. You just won’t believe how vastly hugely mind-boggingly big it is. I mean you may think it’s a long way down the road to the chemist, but that’s just peanuts to space.

—Douglas Adams, *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*

Specifically space is big compared to the size of even normal stars, and of course black holes are many times smaller than stars. Stars are so small compared to the spacing between them that even in a collision between two galaxies it's very rare for any stars to actually collide. Stellar collisions in an unperturbed galaxy like the Milky Way will be vanishingly rare.

Black hole collisions are expected to happen, but only in rather special circumstances. For example about half of the larger stars in the Milky Way are in binary or multiple systems, and some fraction of these will evolve into systems with two or more black holes. Two orbiting black holes will shed energy be emitting gravitational waves and they will slowly spiral inwards towards each other and eventually merge.

Alternatively when galaxies collide and merge dynamical friction will probably cause the two supermassive black holes to approach and merge.

Mergers of binary black holes are the only ones we're likely to be able to observe on human timescales. No-one is sure how many mergers there are per year in the Milky Way but I've seen estimates in the range of 100 to 1000. One of the aims of the [LIGO experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) is to observe these mergers, though only now after a recent upgrade is LIGO approaching the required sensitivity. At the time of writing no mergers, or indeed any other form of gravitational wave, have been detected.

Comment: +1 for the citation (and the answer) :). By the way, the speed of such collisions will be nowhere near the speed of light; it will be of the order of the virial velocity of the galaxies, i.e. a few hundreds to maximum a few thousands km/s.